# Formatting a date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that shows the newest book with a date format of `"January 3, 2011"` but I keep getting errors when trying to format the date.

Below is the working query without the date formatted:

```
SELECT title, pubdate 
FROM   books
WHERE  pubdate =
       ( SELECT MAX(pubdate)
         FROM   books );
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are really using.  MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: What errors is it that you see? What formatting is it that you have tried? Cheers

Comment: I am using oracle and date is currently stored as DD-MM-YY

Comment: Is the `pubdate` column defined as a `DATE` column? If you describe the table, does it say `DATE` next to the column? For this type of question we need to know. What you tried and what the errors were would also be useful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pubdate` is defined as a `DATE` column, you can format it with `to_char`:

```
to_char(pubdate, 'fmMonth dd, YYYY') as pubdate
```

This converts it into a string in the specified format (but lets the language default to the user's `nls_date_language` setting).

Dates in Oracle are not strings that you store in some format. They contain binary data and you must format them how you want when you display them. (Sometimes people store dates as strings, which apart from being a bad idea can create confusion when they ask about formatting them differently.)

Answer (score 1):

use `To_char` convert `Datetime` to your expect format string.

Here is a sample.

```
CREATE TABLE books(pubdate Date, title varchar(50));

insert into books values ('18-Mar-06','A');

insert into books values ('11-Nov-06','B');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT title,To_char(pubdate,'MON DD, YYYY')  pubdate
FROM books
WHERE pubdate =
    (SELECT MAX(pubdate)
     FROM books)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67feb/4/0)**:

```
| TITLE |      PUBDATE |
|-------|--------------|
|     B | NOV 11, 2006 |
```

Comment: When adding the to_date with that formatting I receive "not a valid month error"

Comment: What's you data for pubdate column?

Comment: The data type is Date and it displays as DD-MM-YY

Comment: I mean you data string

Comment: I think OP is trying to convert from a DATE to a VARCHAR2 - they probably want `to_char()`

Comment: 11-Nov-06, 18-Mar-06, 01-Mar-06, etc.

Comment: @Mitch Ok I know your question You can try my edit answer

Comment: @Mitch: As you say the data type is `DATE` you should not invoke `TO_DATE` on it. By applying `to_date(pubdate,'YY-MON-DD')` you are asking Oracle to silently convert your date to a string, then try to convert this string using the format 'YY-MON-DD', which may or may not work, depending on session settings for dates. Don't do this. See William Robertson's answer on how to display a date in the desired format.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for your remind I didn't see the `pubdate` datatype is  date from comments.